# Clipping a TIGER Census Tract by Vector Outline

Tags: qgis

So I have recently downloaded the 2011 Tiger Census Tract for the 5 Boroughs of Manhattan which I would like to process for a future visualization.

The Tract Shp file includes water areas, which I would like to clip out using the actual boundaries of each borough.

Or in other words how do I clip the blue tract areas using the red outlines.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Because the red outlines in the image do not indicate polygonal regions in any unambiguous way--which portions should be included and which ones not?--your task is impossible to do without more information than stated in this post.  Why don't you represent the tracts as actual polygons--which is the form they usually come in--rather than as mere outlines?

Answer (score 1):

As @whuber is suggesting, doing a clip will leave you with a lot of strange and unaccurate geometry - think about how you'll clip the boroughs in the SE part of the map - they're islands, and you won't end up with accurate tracts in the end.

What you want to do is a simple spatial selection, and grab the tracts that intersect the boroughs.

To do this, use the QGIS menu > Vector > Spatial Query:

Note the source feature is the tracts, the 'where' feature is Boroughs, and I used the 'intersect' to grab those that basically 'touch' the boroughs feature

[image]

You'll end up with tracts that are whole, though they might fall outside of the border of your Boroughs...

[image]